# Ubuntu 12.04 won't load on Windows 8 + DELL Inspiron 14z

Tags: dell, windows-8, ultrabook

I've installed Ubuntu from my windows 8, using Daemon Tools to emulate the CD/DVD driver, and it appeared to be quite successful, but when I tried to reboot the computer, I got stuck on the UEFI, with two options: Windows 8 and Ubuntu, only that Ubuntu option won't work, it shows this error:

```
File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr
State: 0xc000007b
```

And I've got one extra serious problem: my CD/DVD driver is not working. (And that's why i had to emulate it from windows 8, in order to install Linux)

I can disable secure boot and prioritize stuff to boot, but it does not seem to work.
Any suggestion?

Comment: This because of your windows 8 installation. Read this- http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0):

Preinstalled Windows8 are always in UEFI mode.
You have installed Ubuntu inside Windows (via the Wubi installer), but unfortunately Wubi is not compatible with UEFI.

So you should not use Wubi, but install Ubuntu the standard way. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Preinstalled windows 8 use 2 things: UEIF and GPT (GUID Partition Table). where as Linux system doesn't support GPT at all, it supports MBR partition table. If u try to install Ubuntu, it will not detect Windows 8 partition.

The only solution is to remove all the partition from the disk, clean the disk and initialize the disk as mbr disk instead of GPT.

Follow the link to delete GPT:

http://www.sizledcore.com/2010/11/how-to-delete-gpt-protective-partition-in-windows/

After deleting GPT you will loose all the data on disk. so please take backup of data and make sure you have Windows 8 installer with KEY to activate.

After making disk as MBR disk, you can go for dual boot.